# Conditional validation with bootstrapValidator only if country is US or Canada

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrapValidator and I am trying to figure out a way to only validate the phone format if the selected country is USA, Canada or other [NANP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers#United_States.2C_Canada.2C_and_other_NANP_countries) countries since it only can check formats for those countries.

In my "onReady" section of my java script I have:

```
billingPhone: {
        validators: {
                notEmpty: {
              message: 'Phone is required and can\'t be empty'
            },
            phone: {
              message: 'Format is invalid'
            }
        }
},
```

I have a select with countries and an input with phone (among other fields) I have a script that also changes a value isNANP to either true or false based on the value of the country select.  But I can't figure out how to wrap the `if(isNANP)` around the phone validator.

I tried to set the enable value (see below) either false or true but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
billingPhone: {
        validators: {
                notEmpty: {
              message: 'Phone is required and can\'t be empty'
            },
            phone: {
              message: 'Format is invalid',
              enabled: isNNAP ? true : false
            }
        }
},
```

Comment: Maybe you can wrap the validator inside the select check? Like if the select is set to US you run the validator.

Comment: @Lance If possible, post can post `html`, `css`, `js` ?

Comment: Did you try simply `enabled: isNNAP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a validation rule to suit your need. here is a sample implementation:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.bootstrapValidator.validators.customPhone = {
        html5Attributes: {
            message: 'message',
            field: 'field',
            check_only_for: 'check_only_for'
        },

        /**
         * Return true if the input value contains a valid US phone number only
         *
         * @param {BootstrapValidator} validator Validate plugin instance
         * @param {jQuery} $field Field element
         * @param {Object} options Consist of key:
         * - message: The invalid message
         * - field: The name of field that will be used to get selected country
         * - check_only_for : Coma separated ISO 3166 country codes // i.e. 'us,ca'
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        validate: function(validator, $field, options) {
            var value = $field.val();
            if (value == '') {
                return true;
            }

            var countryField = validator.getFieldElements(options.field);

            if (countryField == null) {
                return true;
            }

            var countryCode = countryField.val().trim();

            if(countryCode == ''){
                return true;
            }

            var check_list = options.check_only_for.toUpperCase().split(',')

            if(check_list.indexOf(countryCode.toUpperCase()) == -1) {
                return true;
            }

            value = value.replace(/\(|\)|\s+/g, '');
            return (/^(?:1\-?)?(\d{3})[\-\.]?(\d{3})[\-\.]?(\d{4})$/).test(value);
        }
    }
}(window.jQuery));
```

Use this after you have loaded the bootstrap Validator. Then you can assign the validation rule like:

```
billingPhone: {
    validators: {
        notEmpty: {
            message: 'Phone is required and can\'t be empty'
        },
        customPhone: {
            message: 'Format is invalid',
                check_only_for: 'us,ca',
                field: 'country'
        }
    }
},
```

Where **field** is The name of field that will be used to get selected country. and **check_only_for** should list all the country code you want to check for validation role.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks This is exactly what I was trying to figure out!